# How to integrate Javascript library in Laravel9 with Vue using Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-8

new to all these modern day frameworks
I'm trying to get this javascript library to work in my Vue component: https://clipboardjs.com

I can see it is integrated into my public/js/app.js file when Mix runs - but I cannot seem to be able to reference it from within my .vue (component) file

Can anyone give me a step by step guide on how to get this to integrate into my project please:

resources/js/app.js file

```
 import './clipboard';
```

the clipboard.js file is located at:

resources/js/clipboard.js

Mix webpack.mix.js file:

```
mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
 .js("resources/js/clipboard.js", "public/js")
 .vue()
 .postCss("resources/css/app.css", "public/css", [
   require("tailwindcss"),
 ]);
```

My Vue component (method section):

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['mediaDetails'],
        data() {
            return {
            }
        },
        methods: {
              copyPassword() {
            alert("copy");
            var password = document.getElementById('#password');
            alert('1');
             var clipboard = new ClipboardJS(password);
            alert('2');
          }
        }
```

the alert('2') never fires due to the clipboard assignemnet failing

Comment: You don't seems to import that npm package anywhere ?

Answer (score 1):

1. First, in your `webpack.mix.js` file, remove the line `.js("resources/js/clipboard.js", "public/js")`
2. Install the `clipboard` package: `npm install clipboard`
3. In your Vue component, import the package in order to use it:

```html
<script>
   import ClipboardJS from 'clipboard';

   export default {
       props: ['mediaDetails'],
       data() {
           return {
           }
       },
       methods: {
             copyPassword() {
           alert("copy");
           var password = document.getElementById('#password');
           alert('1');
            var clipboard = new ClipboardJS(password);
           alert('2');
         }
       }
```

4. BTW You have a typo error in `document.getElementById('#password')`, it should be `document.getElementById('password')`

Comment: Thanks @DVN-Anakin. I will give this a go and report back.  Thanks for your help.